Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPs on same port in Apache reverse proxy
I've got a reverse proxy operating on port 2000 using Apache.
It's listening to another web server on the same port which is broadcasting HTTP.
I can get the reverse proxy functioning fine, and HTTPS working, and when I go to http:// it returns a 400 Bad Request, which is good.
However, I want to automatically redirect any HTTP traffic to HTTPS. I've tried using RewriteEngine, to no avail.
I'm using Docker Compose and this config is in the httpd configuration.
An example where the HTTPS works fine but the redirect does not occur:
<VirtualHost *:2000>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /crt/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /crt/key.key

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://dockercontainer:2000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://dockercontainer:2000/
</VirtualHost>

They all need to match the same port.
Thanks.
